# Material UI autocomplete with multi-select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here's what I am trying to do. I would like to maintain state for a multi-select Autocomplete from by just using an array of strings to maintain that state. I do, however, need an array of objects to store the relationship between the strings representing state on the backend and the label I want to display for the autocomplete. In the below example, I want to store on the front end the values ['DB_A', 'DB_C'] as the values for state (this is because all available options are available asynchronously and separately from the actual selected options when stored, but I want to display with the multiselect the labels associated with those values in state. Here's what I expect to happen with the below code:

1. Empty array provided, nothing displayed.
2. Select A choice from dropdown.
3. I expect the onChange to fire which then has the callback execute. val would be

```
[{ id: 'DB_A', label: 'A choice' }]
```

which then gets passed to map and setSelOptions would then be set with ['DB_A']. Great.
At this point, the chip doesn't display correctly despite the getOptionSelected function telling the component to say a value is select if it is equal to the option.id. Problem 1.

4. Problem 2. Select C Choice from dropdown.
5. I expect val to come back as

```
[{ id: 'DB_A', label: 'A choice' }, { id: 'DB_C', label: 'C Choice' }]
```

or

```
[{ id: 'DB_C', label: 'C Choice' }]
```

so that I can append the result of map to the end of the selOptions array via setSelOptions callback function. Instead what I get is

```
['DB_A', { id: 'DB_C', label: 'C Choice' }]
```

This is almost impossible to work with as now I have to test whether each value of var is either a string or an object and handle it accordingly. This CANNOT be what is intended, but I cannot figure out anything better in this API. Code below, and working sandbox below that.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Autocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

import "./styles.css";
const options = [
  {id: 'DB_A', label: 'A choice'},
  {id: 'DB_B', label: 'B choice'},
  {id: 'DB_C', label: 'C choice'},
]
function App() {
  const [selOptions, setSelOptions] = React.useState([])
  console.log(selOptions)
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="using-simple-state"
      value={selOptions}
      multiple
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={opt => opt.label}
      getOptionSelected={((o, v) => o.id === v)}
      onChange={(_event, val, _reason) => {
        console.log(val)
        setSelOptions(val.map(v => v.id))
      }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="How can I make this work?"
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-autocomplete-l7syq?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Autocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

import "./styles.css";
const options = [
  {id: 'DB_A', label: 'A choice'},
  {id: 'DB_B', label: 'B choice'},
  {id: 'DB_C', label: 'C choice'},
]
const optionMap = Object.fromEntries(options.map(e => [e.id, e.label]))
function App() {
  const [selOptions, setSelOptions] = React.useState([])
  console.log(selOptions)
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="using-simple-state"
      multiple
      value={selOptions}
      onChange={(_event, val) => {
        setSelOptions(val)
      }}
      options={options.map(c => c.id)}
      getOptionLabel={opt => optionMap[opt]}
      renderInput={params => {
        return (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="How can I make this work?"
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
        />
      )}}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Alright this works. Key is to separately store the id, and label as an object or map that maps the DB_A values to the appropriate label and then use that object separate from the options in autocomplete to get the label information.